# Bash. String concatenation in loop

Tags: xml, bash, git-bash

I want to take `sitemap.xml` file and replace `lastmod` with new timestamp.

**Exaple of sitemap.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset>
  <url>
    <lastmod>2020-08-02T07:30:53+00:00</lastmod>
    <priority>1.00</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <lastmod>2020-08-02T07:30:53+00:00</lastmod>
    <priority>0.80</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

And my code:

```sh
field=lastmod
timestamp="$(date --iso-8601=seconds)"
sitemap=""

IFS=$'\r\n'
for line in $(cat ./sitemap.xml)    
do
  case $line in
    *"<$field>"*"</$field>"* )
    pre=${line#*"<$field>"}
    suf=${line%"</$field>"*}
    line="${line%$pre}${timestamp}${line#$suf}"
    ;;
  esac
  sitemap=$sitemap$line$'\n'
done

# echo $sitemap > sitemap.xml
echo $sitemap
```

The code above should read the file, replace needed tags and output them. Here I'm trying to concatenate strings of file for later saving. And also I'm trying to add `\n` to each line.

But the output of this code doesn't have new lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   <url>     <lastmod>2020-08-22T15:35:47+03:00</lastmod>     <priority>1.00</priority>   </url>   <url>     <lastmod>2020-08-22T15:35:47+03:00</lastmod>     <priority>0.80</priority>   </url> </urlset>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to quote your assignment to *sitemap*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `echo $sitemap` with `echo "$sitemap"`

Answer (score 1):

I did not look at 'what you are doing wrong', but this is an alternative (you only need to adapt the format of the `date`):

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u //lastmod -v "`date`" sitemap.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset>
  <url>
    <lastmod>Sat Aug 22 14:51:59 CEST 2020</lastmod>
    <priority>1.00</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <lastmod>Sat Aug 22 14:51:59 CEST 2020</lastmod>
    <priority>0.80</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

like this:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u //lastmod -v "$(date --iso-8601=seconds)" sitemap.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset>
  <url>
    <lastmod>2020-08-22T14:53:46+02:00</lastmod>
    <priority>1.00</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <lastmod>2020-08-22T14:53:46+02:00</lastmod>
    <priority>0.80</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. But I want to run it in the pre-commit git hook via `git-bash`. And `git-bash` doesn't have `xmlstarlet`

Comment: LOL, it is available for Linux and  windows, see: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php

Comment: Maybe. But git-bash says `bash: xmlstarlet: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

### Use Quotes to Preserve or Append Newlines

Shell quoting and expansion rules can be tricky. You need to quote your assignment to *sitemap*. For example:

```
sitemap="$sitemap$line"
```

You also will likely need to quote your arguments to echo. If you really want to append a newline to the end of your concatenated string, you either have to perform the expansion outside the quotes, use the `-e` flag with echo, or just perform another echo. You could also use printf. As examples:

- `echo "${sitemap}${line}"$'\n'`
- `echo -e "${sitemap}${line}\n"`
- `printf "%s%s\n" "$sitemap" "$line"`

If you need the newlines elsewhere you can move them around, but the principles will still be the same.